# Finding a coordinate system in which coordinate lines are geodesic lines

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

The problem asks to, in a static spacetime with line element
$$\mathrm{d}s^{2} = -\left(1+\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)\mathrm{d}t^{2} + \mathrm{d}l^{2},$$
with $\mathrm{d}l^{2}$ a 3-Euclidean metric, find a system whose coordinate lines are geodesic lines.

I have no clue of what path to follow to complete this problem. I have tried to use the Euler–Lagrange equations to obtain the geodesic lines, but at the end I am not sure if the answer will show up by solving the Euler–Lagrange equations. Thank you for your answers and help of any kind.

Comment: By "3-Euclidean metric" do you mean it is the flat metric? I.e., $\mathrm{d}l^2 = \mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2 + \mathrm{d}z^2$ in Cartesian coordinates? Or is it just an arbitrary Riemannian metric? If the latter, then what is the meaning of $x$ in your expression?

Comment: You should look for tetrad formalism